# Как добавить разделитель/сепаратор в StatusStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как добавить разделитель/сепаратор/вертикальную разделительную линию в [StatusStrip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения задачи <s>нужно</s> можно добавить к [StatusStrip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=netframework-4.7.2) элемент [ToolStripStatusLabel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel?view=netframework-4.7.2) использовать его свойства [BorderSides](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.bordersides?view=netframework-4.7.2) и [BorderStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.borderstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```cs
toolStripStatusLabel2.BorderSides = ToolStripStatusLabelBorderSides.Left;
toolStripStatusLabel2.BorderStyle = Border3DStyle.Etched;
toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "";
```

[image: Сепаратор в StatusStrip]